# FFMPEG - Converting from WAV to AAC changes the length of the audio file and causes video to be out of sync

Tags: ffmpeg, sync, aac, wav

Disclaimer: I am a complete novice at computer science, coding, etc.

**TLDR: Converting from wav to aac with libfdk_aac is giving me a shorter file, and using aac it turns out longer. How can I preserve the length of the original wav file?**

I extracted two audio sources from an mkv file using:
*ffmpeg -i video.mkv -map a:0 audio1.wav -map a:1 audio2.wav*

Converted the mkv file to an mp4 with no audio using:
*ffmpeg -i video.mkv -c:v copy -an video.mp4 (not sure if copy is appropriate here, but not the point).*

I edited my extracted audio files, exported them as a single wav file, and at this point the new audio file, mkv file, and mp4 file are all the same length.

I tried combining the new audio file and mp4 file using: *ffmpeg -i video.mp4 -i newaudio.wav -c:v copy -c:a libfdk_aac newvideo.mp4*

The audio in the resulting video is delayed. I tried doing this step with more specific mapping and also with a defined bit rate but no luck.

I then tried converting the wav file to acc as a single step first and this is where the problem seems to be. The aac file ends up shorter than the wav file using libfdk_aac, and with the default aac it comes out longer.

How can I ensure the converted aac file is the same length as the input wav file?

Thanks :)